# Click funcionando errado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho esse código:

```js
function loadEditLabel() {
  // Salva o novo input saindo do campo ou apertando enter
  $('[contenteditable="true"]').focus().select().keydown(function(event) {
      if (event.key == 'Enter') { // Checa se a tecla digitada foi o Enter
        $(this).prev('input').val(this.innerHTML); // Colocar o value do input com o texto digitado
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false); // Desabilita o campo de edição
      }
    })
    .blur(function() {
      $(this).prev('input').val(this.innerHTML);
      $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
    });
}

$('#add').click(function() {
  html = '<div>';
  html += '<input type="radio" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" value="teste" name="data">';
  html += '<input type="text" placeholder="Nova Entrada">';
  html += '</div>';

  $('#radios').append(html); // Adiciona o novo input dentro da div radios

  loadEditLabel(); // Carrega o radio para a edição
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group esconder" id="id_2">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="multipla-escolha">
        <label class="" for="orderBy">Pergunta</label>
        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Pergunta">
        <div class="container">
          <div id="radios">
            <div>
              <input type="radio" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" value="teste" name="data"><input type="text" value="Opção 1">
            </div>
          </div>
          <button id="add">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ele serve para adicionar `radios`, mas só que deveria adicionar apenas quando clicasse no `button`, só que qualquer *click* que eu dou, inclusive em outras páginas, adicionam radio para essa modal `dialog`.

Comment: Se executar o código apresentado na pergunta, verá que o novo elemento só é adicionado ao clicar no botão `+`, então tem como [edit] a pergunta e detalhar melhor o problema?

Comment: Eu coloquei um alert na função do js, e ele dá alert em qualquer clicks que dou a partir da modal fade, ou seja, esse click ta está adicionando os radios. Não sei pq, mas esse click que deveria ser exclusivo do button add, está executando quando dou qualquer especie de click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue abaixo a possível resposta para o seu problema.

Ao criar o evento `$('#add').click` você está dizendo ao jQuery que toda vez que houver um `click` em qualquer tipo de elemento no seu documento que contenha o ID "add" ele execute esse trecho de código.

Provavelmente, em suas outras páginas deve conter algum elemento pai com o id `add`, e nesse caso o javascript estaria simplemente interpretando o seu código.

Para resolver, tente modificar o id do botão para algo que você não tenha usado em sua página. Exemplo: "btnAddPaginaTal", e modifique tanto no seu botão o id quanto no jquery o código.

> Nota: Eu testei o seu código e comigo não ocorreu o problema, então acredito que seja um elemento pai com o id "add" que esteja causando esse problema.

Veja no [JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/bzo8zdyp/) com o seu código funcionando.

Comment: Nossa, era isso mesmo. Obrigada!!!

Comment: Marque a resposta como correta por favor :)